# Multiplication in input with comma and special character

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input, var

The goal is: If I write in first input 10,000 (which should be 10000) and multiply it by 0.005 then must be 50, but now is 0,50 - Just remove "," when using multiplication.

Also I want to add "$" symbol when function showing me final value. ($10000)

```
<input type="text" id="results-input-1"></p>
<input type="text" id="results-input-2" value="0.005"/>

<span id="results-cal-final">$</span>

<script>
var multiplyShares = function() {
   var val1 = parseFloat($('#results-input-1').val())
   var val2 = parseFloat($('#results-input-2').val())

   val3 = val1 * val2 || "Invalid"
   $("#results-cal-final").html(val3)
}
$("#results-input-1").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
$("#results-input-2").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `,` using `$('#results-input-1').val().replace(/,/g, "")`.

The proper location to add `$` is at `.html()`. You can also call `.toFixed(2)` to add decimal places in the displayed value.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Type 10,000 below:<br>

<input type="text" id="results-input-1"></p>
<input type="text" id="results-input-2" value="0.005"/>

<span id="results-cal-final">$</span>

<script>
var multiplyShares = function() {
   var val1 = parseFloat($('#results-input-1').val().replace(/,/g, ""))
   var val2 = parseFloat($('#results-input-2').val())

   var val3 = val1 * val2;
   if (val3) {
     // add two decimals if needed, prepend $
     val3 = "$" + /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(val3+'') ? val3.toFixed(2) : val3);
   } else {
     val3 = "Invalid";
   }

   $("#results-cal-final").html(val3)
}
$("#results-input-1").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
$("#results-input-2").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
</script>
```

Comment: Great code. It's possible to hide "$" when value is "Invalid"?

Comment: I did. I updated the question quickly after I posted it. Just retry the code.

Comment: Now, there is a problem if I write "1" in first input then is a wrong final value.

Comment: Its due to the `.toFixed(2)`, it is rounding to two decimal places. It can be removed.

Comment: Yes, I saw. Rather than min="2" in input what I should use to make it work when is "1"?

Comment: Can you give it a try again?

Comment: Hello. I have made a small adjustement to the function, I suggest you use this updated code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as below for a crude idea of the solution. 
Replace all the `,` by the empty space and multiply normally as you are doing.

```html
    
<input type="text" id="results-input-1"></p>
<input type="text" id="results-input-2" value="0.005"/>

<span id="results-cal-final"></span>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
var multiplyShares = function() {
   var val1 = parseFloat($('#results-input-1').val().replace(',',''))
   var val2 = parseFloat($('#results-input-2').val())

   val3 = val1 * val2 || "Invalid"
   $("#results-cal-final").html(val3 !== 'Invlid' ? ('$' + val3) : 'Invlid')
}
$("#results-input-1").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
$("#results-input-2").keyup(function() { multiplyShares(); });
</script>
```